# Why are floating-point primitive types, when divided and multiplied by certain multiples of 10, are displayed in scientific notation?

Tags: java, floating-point, language-design

In the example below can see that Java has a peculiarity when displaying the result in certain types of operations with primitive types that have floating point, such as division by multiples of 10:

```
int num1 = 5;
float num2 = num1 / 10000f;
System.out.println (num2);
```

As can be [seen here](https://ideone.com/NH32OI), the result is `5.0E-4` and not `0.0005`.

I understand that this is a scientific notation, which means `5.0 * 10 ^ -4`, which leads to the same value, but I did not understand why Java makes this change in the display.

There is a [snippet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString-float-) of the documentation that says:

> (...) If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation."

Is there any convention or official motive for language to adopt such a display in the case mentioned in the citation? Or is it just for readability?

> Note: this feature does not occur with `int` and`long` types, such as [**seen here**](https://ideone.com/7h7UMx)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a doc reference for this, but in general it can get to be difficult to read very large, or very small numbers.  The reason is that, as you may test yourself, it is hard to count number of zeroes, when that number becomes large.  Actually, one of the points of scientific notation is to avoid writing insignificant zeroes.

Taking as an example the number `5.0E-4`, we *could* write it as `0.0005`.  But the zeroes before the `5` are *insignificant*, and only contribute to the measurement by telling us that it is reasonably small.  By writing this value as `5.0E-4`, we relegate the zeroes to the `E-4` term, allowing us to focus on the significant `5.0` value.

As to why Java chose its particular convention, you might have to ask the creators of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can force either scientific or fixed-point output using formatting (as in `String.format`) using `%e` or `%f` respectively. For example, just change the last line to

```
System.out.printf("%.4f\n", num2);
```

But, by default, string conversion is supposed to use, you are right, a format that seems most "friendly" to a human reader and avoid useless details. Details can slightly differ in various implementations. For example, C standard says for `%g`:

> The style used depends on the value converted; style e (or E) is used only if the exponent resulting from such a conversion is less than −4 or greater than or equal to the precision.

("Precision" is parameter after period; e.g. in `%20.11g` precision is 11.)

For reasoning of concrete values, as -4, one can compare presentations of different values in 'F', 'E' and 'G' forms. For an upper bound, if exponent is less than precision, the scientific form is useless because printed exponent will be 0. For a lower bound, -4 seems is also related to length of exponent suffix like `e-05`: 1e-05 is considered better read than 0.00001.

This selection of three formats and adaptive behavior of 'G' format is originating in very early ages, such as 1960s with `Fortran`. IBM Fortran 4 was already providing these three format styles with the same basic meaning as now.

Iʼm not a standard lawyer and answer this basing only with pieces of information gathered from different sources. For a complete answer you could ask a standard makers. But I hope the picture Iʼve described is rather exact to grok the concept.